# Why do I get this error when executing this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show when the drcr 2 then amount is Debit and when drcr 1 then amount is credit,and  when IsOpening is 1 and drcr is 2 then amount is OpeningDebit and when Isopening is 1 and drcr is 1 then amount is openingCredit.

```
SELECT   
    GL.AccountId,Ca.Code as Code,
    CA.AccountName as AccountName,
    SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN GL.Amount END) AS Debit,
    SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN GL.Amount END) AS Credit,
    SUM(CASE GL.IsOpening WHEN 1 THEN Case GL.DrCr When 2 Then  GL.Amount END) AS OpeningDebit,
    SUM(CASE GL.IsOpening WHEN 1 THEN Case GL.DrCr When 1 Then  GL.Amount END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM 
    GeneralLedgerLine GL 
JOIN
    ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id 
WHERE
    CA.ClientId = 1
GROUP BY 
    GL.AccountId, CA.Code, CA.AccountName
```

[image: Table]

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: So where the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - you've missed the `END` for `outer CASE WHEN` expression

```
SELECT   GL.AccountId,Ca.Code as Code,CA.AccountName as AccountName,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN GL.Amount END) AS Debit,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN GL.Amount END) AS Credit,
         SUM(CASE GL.IsOpening WHEN 1 THEN Case GL.DrCr When 2 Then  GL.Amount END END) AS OprningDebit,
         SUM(CASE GL.IsOpening WHEN 1 THEN Case GL.DrCr When 1 Then  GL.Amount END END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM     GeneralLedgerLine GL Join ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id Where CA.ClientId = 1
GROUP BY GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName
```

OR You can simply do like below -

```
SELECT   GL.AccountId,Ca.Code as Code,CA.AccountName as AccountName,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN GL.Amount END) AS Debit,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN GL.Amount END) AS Credit,
         SUM(CASE GL.IsOpening WHEN 1 and GL.DrCr =2 Then  GL.Amount END) AS OprningDebit,
         SUM(CASE GL.IsOpening WHEN 1 and GL.DrCr=1 Then  GL.Amount END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM     GeneralLedgerLine GL Join ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id Where CA.ClientId = 1
GROUP BY GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName
```

Answer (score 2):

You may make wrong in your condition..

```
SELECT   
  GL.AccountId,
  Ca.Code as Code,
  CA.AccountName as AccountName,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GL.DrCr = 2 THEN GL.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Debit,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GL.DrCr = 1 THEN GL.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Credit,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GL.IsOpening = 1 AND GL.DrCr = 2 THEN GL.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS OpeningDebit,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GL.IsOpening = 1 AND GL.DrCr = 1 THEN GL.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM 
  GeneralLedgerLine GL 
  INNER JOIN ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id 
Where 
  CA.ClientId = 1
GROUP BY 
  GL.AccountId,
  CA.Code,
  CA.AccountName
```

You should handled your `CASE` condition when the condition not met or it will become `Null`..